# Compile Error: Expected: Expression PivotTable

Tags: vba, excel, pivot, excel-2010

I'm currently having this issue while running VBA code. I've created code that downloads a report from SAP GUI and with that spreadsheet I need to create a PivotTable. I used the Macro Recorder to create the pivot but I'm having this issue while running it.

```
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Sheets.Add
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Sheet1!R1C1:R1500C18", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable
    TableDestination:="Sheet4!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion _
    :=xlPivotTableVersion14
Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Cells(3, 1).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Company Code")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("FI / MM Doc")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Document number"), "Count of Document number", _
    xlCount
```

The issue appears in the `Tabledestination:="Sheet4!R3C1"`, row showing up the ":=" as an unexpected error.

Do you guys know how can I solve this?

Comment: Does `Sheet4` exist when you attempt to run this code? If so, what's on this worksheet before you run the code? It could be that it can't put the PivotTable in the location you're specifying. Also, what is the error message and number that you're getting?

Comment: No, the Sheet4 doesn't exists. The error I'm getting is 1004 Compile Error Expected: Expression focusing in the ":="

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `_` symbol to carry over the statement to the next line. That will eliminate your compile error.

However, I'd also look at ensuring your references to `Sheet4` are okay: when you add a new worksheet, there's no guarantee that Excel will call it `Sheet4`, so either you should force the name in the `.Add` statement, or don't explicitly refer to it as `Sheet4` after the creation of the pivot table. When Excel adds a sheet, the new sheet becomes the active one anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much Mark! I've followed your advice and now it works!